# ImageView visible on the VideoView?

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview, android-videoview

I would like to have the possibility to set visible an image in the imageview (
that occupies half screen) while playing a video in a videoview. It's possible to do that?

Comment: Yes it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a xml like this,

Add equal weight for the views and make there height 0dp, it will take equal height.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

  <ImageView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:background="#ccc"
      />
  <VideoView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      />
</LinearLayout>
```

It will help you.

Comment: Thank u, I'm trying to do that in a Relative Layout like this, but the video is over the image when I change the image visibility... And I would like to have the opposite, and so the image over the video.

Comment: answer is updated,please have a look and let me know,whether this is the thing you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Thank u, I'm trying to do that in a Relative Layout like this, but the video is over the image when I change the image visibility... And I would like to have the opposite, and so the image over the video.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".PatternSelection" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/settse"
        android:layout_width="480dp"
        android:layout_height="270dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/sett" />

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```